# Array access is not constant

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, machine-code

Lets say we have an array **A** and its first element is **a** with adress **adr**.
When we want to access nth element, at machine level we must first calculate **adr + n*a[size]**, then access the element.

As we see the calculation of nth element's adress depend on **n**, and big **n** means much more step of calculation

So why saying that accessing array is constant time?

I searching why its like that, but i didnt found

Comment: *"big n means much more step of calculation"* - What makes you say that? What "step"?

Comment: Why would multiplication not be just constant time? Does `8 * 10` take more time than `2 * 10`?

Comment: As i know (maybe i am wrong) in machine level (micro-instructions), multiplication will not be constant, it depend on `n`.

Comment: This time complexity usually assumes fixed size integers, but if we consider that arrays can have sizes greater than -- let's say -- 2<sup>64</sup> words, then indeed you'd have a time complexity that depends on the multiplication algorithm for big integers. But this is only of theoretical importance, as memory size is practically limited to much, much less. There are today to my knowledge no computers yet that have an internal memory size (suitable for array indexing) of 2^64 words.

Comment: *O(n)* is an abstract concept from computer science. It doesn't really care about machine-level micro instructions, so it assumes basic algebraic operations as constant (unless of course you are talking about the complexity of an multiplication algorithm)

Comment: @trincot and derpirscher thank you very much.
You mean that because multiplication is very very fast we can just ignore its time complexity and consider it as constant. Right?

Comment: No, it is because we use fixed size integers for this type of multiplication.

Comment: ...and the effort to multiply two fixed-sized integers is the same, no matter what the actual values are of those integers. CPUs are just "wired" to perform the multiplication in a fixed number of cycles. Time complexity only becomes relevant when the operands of the multiplication cannot be assured to fit in those fixed size integers, and you need the concept of big integers (multiple words). But that is not relevant for the topic of array indexing.

Comment: I think now i get the idea. thank you very much @trincot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that multiplication of larger numbers takes a bit longer on some processors, though here these days, we're talking about a few extra cycles even for very, very large numbers.  Put another way, multiplication scales very well indeed.

Even using a shift and add approach we can put a maximum on the complexity of the multiplication, of say 32 or 64 iterations of the shift-add loop.

---

> As we see the calculation of nth element's address depend on n, and big n means much more step of calculation

Array indexing is done using the following types:

- A base pointer to the start of the array, which is treated by the program and processor as an unsigned integer whose size is the address width of the processor (e.g. 64 bits or 32 bits depending on processor).
- An index to the array, which needs to be scaled by size of elements of the array, this index ultimately is also limited to the same bit width as the above base pointer.

I'd like to point out that in most languages where we are talking about the built-in array mechanisms, there is no way to allocate an array for whom the array indexing calculation will overflow the fixed bit width.  The allocation will fail asking for more memory than the processor can address.  So, this means that all indexing and pointer arithmetic operations that access valid memory (i.e. allocation succeeded) will not overflow and do not need to be checked for overflow in calculation.  (Unless indexing operations are done using a smaller size than the unsigned bit width of the processor, which, sadly, can happen by programmers' choices and/or language defaults.)

Because you cannot allocate an array that exceeds the processors addressing capabilities, we can use fixed-sized arithmetic in indexing computations.  And because of that, we know that the processor can do such indexing in O(1).

Comment: @trincot has answered me, but i thank you also very much. And as an answer must be selected as helpful i select this to close the post. Thank you all